# polkadot canvas testnet contract deploy error "contracts.contractTrapped"

Tags: ink, blockchain

I'm trying to deploy basic erc20 example contract on rococo canvas but "contracts.ContractTrapped" error popped on deployment? most probably it's a problem in INK release version. I'm using rs7.
Any hint will be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Rehan this is a bit outdated by now. We've recently released ink! 3.0 and pushed a few updates to the Canvas runtime as well as the `substrate-contracts-node`.

Answer (score 6):

There is a fix for the `ContractTrapped` error [which just got merged.](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/6973)

Deployment will work on Rococo Canvas soon, after an update which is in progress.

Until then, you can test your contracts on a local node https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node
Make sure you have the latest versions, which at this time are:

- ink 3.0.0 RC8
- substrate-contracts-node v0.6.0
- cargo-contract v0.17.0